# fscanf not placing values in variables

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

I have a 3 values (seperated by spaces) in a file that I'm reading into 3 variables using fscanf. For some reason, the values aren't being changed. When I print the values, it prints memory garbage/whatever I set their initial value to. I've tried using fgets with sscanf as well, but no dice.

The code:

```
int numPresale; // The number of presale tickets sold
double costPresale; // The cost of presale tickets
double costDoor;    // The cost of tickets sold at the door

// Opens the file. Exits program if it can't
if((inFile = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to open the input file '%s'\n", fileName);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Parse for information
fscanf(inFile, "%.2f %.2f %d", &costPresale, &costDoor, &numPresale);

printf("%.2f %.2f %d", costPresale, costDoor, numPresale);

fclose(inFile);
```

I'm sure I'm committing some classic rookie mistake, but I can't find any answers on the web. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Also, always check the return-value. And use full warnings: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the values do not change is that the `fscanf` does not find values that match the format that you specify. In addition, spaces are not required. Finally, since you are reading the data into `double`, not `float`, you should use `%lf` as the format specifier.

You can check that the proper number of items has been received by checking the return value of `fscanf`.

This should fix this problem:

```
if (fscanf(inFile, "%lf%lf%d", &costPresale, &costDoor, &numPresale) == 3) {
    printf("%.2f %.2f %d", costPresale, costDoor, numPresale);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/QIRndR)

Comment: `.2f` does not require two places. For `scanf`, it's simply an invalid format string. The `.` character is not used in `scanf` formats.